# JMeter concurrent user testing

Tags: jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I want to run a 200 concurrent user load on my website with 50 users on different page. Do I need to create multiple thread groups with 50 users each or can I do it in the same thread group.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one thread group using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)